# Symfony JsonResponse Component AndJquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, jsonresponse

I have a problem with Symfony JsonResponse Component that I used in my app.

JsonResponse always return status code 200.

```
return new JsonResponse([], JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
```

and jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: BASE_URL +'/api/cart',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            waitResponse.resolve(response);
        },
        error: function (error, a, b) {
            waitResponse.reject(error);
        }
    })
```

Response always evaluate to error with msg "parseerror", but status code is 200. If I remove dataType: 'json', then is always in success.
Does anybody know how to fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess when sending response from the controller you are not sending the second parameter, by default JsonResponse send 200.

send parameter accordingly

```
$data = null, $status = 200, $headers = array()
```

check this file more details:  `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;`

official doc [JsonResponse](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html)

Comment: I already define response code. It's JsonResponse:HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, which is code 400. So, it must return that code. In symfony app works that way